# iOS simulator becomes slow after upgrading to Xcode 12.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

For some reason my iOS simulator became slow after I updated my Xcode to the latest version (12.1) which includes iPhone 12 support.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by going to **File > GPU Selection** and selecting **Prefer Discrete GPU**.

[image]